# Компилирование less прямиком в браузере

Tags: less

Вопрос к специалистам: на сколько данный способ приемлем/правильный или же лучше с помощью каких то программ это делать вручную?

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less"/>
<script src="/js/less.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот способ можно применять при разработке. Процесс разработки упрощается, поскольку ничего не надо компилировать, т.е. запускать что-то дополнительное. Но для релиза/продакшена это лучше не использовать и ставить в странице ссылку на готовый CSS.

Во-первых, кроме less-файла клиент вынужден будет загрузить и сам компилятор. Хоть он и маленький, но для медленных каналов это может увеличить время загрузки страницы до визуально заметных величин.

Во-вторых, браузер должен будет запустить скрипт-компилятор на выполнение. Это влечёт за собой увеличение нагрузки на клиентскую машину. А если клиент работает на слабеньком смартфоне? Тормоза обеспечены. Кроме того, у клиента может просто стоять запрет выполнения *JavaScript* и ваш с таким трудом написанный стиль просто проигнорируется.

Comment: Очень хорошо объяснили, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Лучше через программы. Используй Gulp или grant. Раз разберешься, потом не сможешь без них.

Comment: Минус за необоснованность.